# Android - how to know if build failed

Tags: android, ant

I'm writing a script which makes my android build with `ant release`, but I need to know if the build succeeded or failed to know how to react. Is there a standardized way of knowing if the build failed when building an Android project from command line with ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit code for a failed build in ant is `1`.
So if the exit code of your `ant` command equals `1` the build has failed.

[Source](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/10/24/getting-return-code-from-ant-in-shell/)